# simpleweather link temperature

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

i'm using jquery with the simpleweather plugin. (I'm programming an app with HTML5 and Cordova)

I have a background-image, which i want to be overlayed by the temperature

-HTML-HEAD-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.simpleWeather({
         location: '',
         woeid: '12474497',
         unit: 'c',
         success: function(weather) {
         html = '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</p>';

         $("#weather").html(html);
         },
         error: function(error) {
         $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
         }
         });
         });
```

-HTML-

```
<div id="third" class="top_navi">
<div id="weather">
   <a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://mobile.wetter.com/', '_blank', 'location=no')"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

-CSS-

```
#third{
background:url(../img/start/btnweather.jpg);
width: 95px;
height: 45px;
}
#third a{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: block;
}
```

Whithout including the Temperature my link works fine, i can click the image and -> my browser opens the link. If i now put in the #weather... the link doesn't work anymore and i get the temperature "13°C". How can i put a link on my image and also get the temperature to be displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is inserting the temperature into the html of #weather where your anchor tags are. Just put your #weather div inside of your anchor tags

```
<a href='#' onclick='do stuff'>
    <div id='weather'>
        //this is where your temp will go
    </div>
</a>
```

Update: to do the temp and link separately

```
<div id='weather'>
        <div id='temp'>
            //this is where your temp will go
       </div>
    <a href='#' onclick='do stuff'>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Jip, now the Temperature is a link, but it's not on my image. it flys through my header :-/

Comment: So you did not want the temp as a link? Sorry if I misunderstood. To do the weather and a link separately. Just put your anchor tags inside of a div and the temperature inside it's own div and then nest those two inside of the div you want them in.